# OrientDB javascript functions return error 400

Tags: javascript, java, database, function, orientdb

When I execute this math javascript function with two parameters from within Studio.

```
return a*b;
```

I get this error

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "code": 400,
        "reason": "Bad request",
        "content": "ScriptManager: error <eval>:1:18 Expected ident but found )\nfunction math(a,b,) {\n                  ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 18.\nFunction math(a,b,):\n\n   1: >>> function math(a,b,) {\n   2: return a*b;\n   3: }\n   4: \n"
    }
  ]
}
```

Background:
I recently upgraded from OrientDB 2.0 to OrientDB 2.1.7. I had not accessed my old db for about a month, and I assumed all my functions where working (as they worked last time).

From console I exported my Demo database from 2.0 to Demo.json.gz  From console I created a new Demo database within 2.1.7 and imported Demo.json.gz.

Ever since then I cannot get my functions to work. It does not matter if I use my Demo database or GratefulDeadConcerts database. Even deleting all files and starting fresh w/out importing Demo still causes the error to happen.

There are some weird quirks where I can get one function to work. If I do not save any other functions as javascript functions, but save them as sql functions I can have one javascript function work. Having multiple functions that use javascript causes all javascript functions to error. This error is also occurring in OrientDB_2.0 now.

I feel this is connected to the first time I imported Demo.json.gz but I do not understand why if I install OrientDB_2.1.7 fresh without importing anything it now still throws the error.

I found on OrientDB google groups other people with the same error [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/orient-database/error$20function$20400/orient-database/_zt4Ff_Ncuc/8Uny7UmtdOMJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/orient-database/error$20function$20400/orient-database/3ByJk559flw/eACXyjo3oHQJ). It appears the solution has been coded in, but unfortunately is not working for me. What to do?

**Update**
I have tested this url parsing function on a new install on a fresh computer. I believe this code is part of the problem, when I fill out the parameters in studio it does update to the db but it also returns another error. This function takes 4 parameters: currentURL, class, title, body.

```
    // remove any slash '/' from end of url
var currentURL = currentURL.replace(/\/$.*/, '');
    // Protocol variable stores the protocol http:// OR http://www. OR www.
var protocol = currentURL.match(/^http[s]?:\/\/www[1-9]?\.|^http[s]?:\/\/|^www[0-9]?\./);    
// Match http(s)://www(0-9) OR http(s):// OR www(0-9) 
var removeProtocol = currentURL.replace(/^http[s]?:\/\/www[1-9]?\.|^http[s]?:\/\/|^www[0-9]?\./, '');
    // removes / and everything after = cnn.com
var domainTLD = removeProtocol.replace(/\/.*/, '');
    // checks string from domainTLD for two periods if yes deletes all characters up to first period.
var urlCheck = domainTLD.replace(/^[^.]*\.(?=[^.]*\.)/, '');   
    // This lines takes urlCheck above and = cnn
var domain = urlCheck.replace(/\..*/, ''); 
    // reformed url = http://www.domain.com
var urlRoot = protocol + domainTLD;
var cleanUrlRoot = urlRoot.replace(/\//gi, '\\/');
var cleanURL = currentURL.replace(/\//gi, '\\/');
var directory = currentURL.replace(urlRoot, '');

//Testing urlEscape
var body = body.replace(/%24/gi, '\\$').replace(/%26/gi, '\\&').replace(/%2B/gi, '\\+').replace(/%2C/gi, '\\,').replace(/%2F/gi, '\\/').replace(/%3A/gi, '\\:').replace(/%3B/gi, '\\;').replace(/%3D/gi, '\\=').replace(/%3F/gi, '\\?').replace(/%40/gi, '\\@').replace(/%93/gi, '\\"').replace(/%3C/gi, '\\<').replace(/%3E/gi, '\\>').replace(/%23/gi, '\\#').replace(/%25/gi, '\\%').replace(/%7B/gi, '\\{').replace(/%7D/gi, '\\}').replace(/%7C/gi, '\\|').replace(/%5C/gi, '\\/').replace(/%5E/gi, '\\^').replace(/%7E/gi, '\\~').replace(/%5B/gi, '\\[').replace(/%5D/gi, '\\]').replace(/%60/gi, '\\`');

var title = title.replace(/%24/gi, '\\$').replace(/%26/gi, '\\&').replace(/%2B/gi, '\\+').replace(/%2C/gi, '\\,').replace(/%2F/gi, '\\/').replace(/%3A/gi, '\\:').replace(/%3B/gi, '\\;').replace(/%3D/gi, '\\=').replace(/%3F/gi, '\\?').replace(/%40/gi, '\\@').replace(/%93/gi, '\\"').replace(/%3C/gi, '\\<').replace(/%3E/gi, '\\>').replace(/%23/gi, '\\#').replace(/%25/gi, '\\%').replace(/%7B/gi, '\\{').replace(/%7D/gi, '\\}').replace(/%7C/gi, '\\|').replace(/%5C/gi, '\\/').replace(/%5E/gi, '\\^').replace(/%7E/gi, '\\~').replace(/%5B/gi, '\\[').replace(/%5D/gi, '\\]').replace(/%60/gi, '\\`');


//---------Time-Manipulation--------//
var currentTime = new Date()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var dated = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;


//when directory contains a string of over 1 character it triggers the system, this is a subdomain url
if (/./.test(directory)) {
  //PROBLEMS work (cnn.com/blah) some do not (http://www.ipinst.org/about/mission-history) regex prob
  db.command("UPDATE " + class + " SET urlSet = \"" + currentURL + "\", title = \"" + title + "\", body = \"" + body + "\", domain = \"" + domain + "\", domainTLD = \"" + domainTLD + "\", dated = \"" + dated + "\", urlRoot = \"" + urlRoot + "\", directory = \"" + directory + "\" UPSERT WHERE urlSet contains \"" + currentURL + "\"");

//  create website root
  db.command("UPDATE website SET urlSet = \"" + urlRoot + "\", title = \"" + domain + "\", domain = \"" + domain + "\", domainTLD = \"" + domainTLD + "\", dated = \"" + dated + "\", urlRoot = \"" + urlRoot +"\" UPSERT WHERE urlSet contains \"" + urlRoot + "\"");


  //create edge from website to sub
  db.command ("CREATE EDGE domain from \(SELECT FROM website where urlSet contains \"" + urlRoot + "\"\) TO \(SELECT FROM V WHERE urlSet contains \"" + currentURL + "\"\)");

} else {
  db.command("UPDATE website SET urlSet = \"" + urlRoot + "\", title = \"" + domain + "\", domain = \"" + domain + "\", domainTLD = \"" + domainTLD + "\", dated = \"" + dated + "\", urlRoot = \"" + urlRoot +"\" UPSERT WHERE urlSet contains \"" + urlRoot + "\"");
}
```

Comment: Hi Soliton, I tried your function in a fresh DB with OrientDB 2.1.7 and It works. I wanted to ask you sharing your "Demo" DB if possible to try this function with your same DB. I also declared `a` and `b` as parameters of the function, is it right ? Have you already tried to re-download the OrientDB 2.1.7 version ?

Comment: Hi LucaS. Yes, I have tried re-downloading orientDB 2.1.7 and starting it w/out using "Demo" db. The problem still exists. Unfortunately I cannot share the Demo db as it has private information. Yes, a and b are parameters. The math function will work with the two parameters as long as it is the only javascript function that exists in studio. I can create multiple math functions and they will work, but as soon as something more technical comes in. All javascript functions stop working.

Comment: Ok, so I installed orientdb-2.1.7 onto a backup computer without importing any databases. From GratefulDeadConcerts all the simple functions work (math etc), using my complex url function I get a similar error but slightly different. I am posting the code and error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The third problem below was the main culprit. On my system naming a parameter "class" causes all javascript functions to error.

First problem, the url parsing function contains a class "website" which only exists in the original db, and does not exist on GratefulDeadConcerts. I have replaced this with "v" class.

The second problem, the "contains" operator on the upsert method is causing an error. This can be replaced with either = or like operator. On my original db I was using contains because I was working on an embedded set. I will have to study more.

Third problem, naming a parameter "class" causes an error within function.

Fixed code:

```
//  create website root **updated** replaced contains with like
  db.command("UPDATE v SET urlSet = \"" + urlRoot + "\", title = \"" + domain + "\", domain = \"" + domain + "\", domainTLD = \"" + domainTLD + "\", dateFluxed = \"" + dateFluxed + "\", urlRoot = \"" + urlRoot +"\" UPSERT WHERE urlSet = \"" + urlRoot + "\"");

  //create edge from website to sub
  db.command ("CREATE EDGE E from \(SELECT FROM v where urlSet like \"" + urlRoot + "\"\) TO \(SELECT FROM V WHERE urlSet like \"" + currentURL + "\"\)");

} else {
  db.command("UPDATE v SET urlSet = \"" + urlRoot + "\", title = \"" + domain + "\", domain = \"" + domain + "\", domainTLD = \"" + domainTLD + "\", dateFluxed = \"" + dateFluxed + "\", urlRoot = \"" + urlRoot +"\" UPSERT WHERE urlSet = \"" + urlRoot + "\"");
}
```

I am a little confused as to why my code didn't work with the database it was made for after importing. But even tho I do not understand, I have gotten the code to work, and not throw errors for everything else. After importing the original db I did notice my indexes where corrupted, so perhaps something occurred which I was not aware of. It also appears that since the function was throwing errors it was affecting all my other functions.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the function you just have to put a simple name without parentheses and parameters otherwise it will give that error.

[image]

See the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Functions.html

Comment: Alessandro Rota, I am not sure I fully understand what you are suggesting. Where am I putting a simple name with parenthesis? I can write the same function as you just wrote, and it will not work as long as I have any other javascript functions saved in studio.